# How to enable a bit in counter control using inline assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, microcontroller

I using inline assembly to enable a bit in counter control register. I am looking out for the apt code in inline-assembly. I used the following code for an [Infineon TriCore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infineon_TriCore) micro-controller.

```
__asm("ENABLE CCTRL.CE");
```

Please guide me in writing the correct code. In the above code, I will need to set 1 to the bit `CE` in Counter Control register (`CCTRL`). Please help.

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding what you actual question here is. What's wrong with the code you have now? (Ps. I edited your question, please check that I didn't make any mistakes.)

Comment: Yes you are correct. The code has some error. I am looking for enabling the bit CE in counter control register.

Comment: which compiler are you using? Is there a SDK for this processor?

Comment: I am using Infenion Tricore TC1797. Tasking is simulation software available.

Comment: The TC1797 is a chip. What _compiler_ are you using?  Did it come with sample software?

Comment: Yeah. Tasking is the sample software and it has compiler as well

Answer (score 1):

A quick scan of the instruction set shows that the  `ENABLE` command is used to enable interrupts.  You probably want the `ST.T` instruction.  There should be something in the SDK which maps the `CCTRL` register to a given memory address or variable name.

Comment: Can you please correct the syntax?  
 __asm("st.t cctrl.ce");
I see this code not working for me.

Comment: There must be an example of how to reference registers somewhere in the documentation of the compiler.  This is a core requirement for programming micro-controllers.